# listing the folder content of another domain on the same server

Tags: php

I have 2 domains on the server. Let say domain1.com and domain2.com I want to list the content of a folder domain2.com/images on domain1.com. I have tried with the following piece of code.

```
$directory  = "domain2.com/images"; 
$images = scandir($directory);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
$count=$count;
echo "<table border=0 style='float:left;margin-left:115px;'>";
foreach($images as $dispimage){
if(!in_array($dispimage, $ignore)){
echo "<tr id='del_pl$count'><td>$count</td><td style='width:300px;'><a href='$directory/$dispimage' target='_blank'>../img/img_large/$dispimage</a></td><td><input type='button' style='padding:0;height:17px;' id='delete$count' value='Delete' onclick='deleteFile(\"$dispimage\",$count,\"$directory\",\"pl\");'></td></tr>";
$count++;
}
}
```

It is not working, can it be that i need to assign some kind of right to do this or the problems is somewhere else. Just for the information, the code is working well if I am working with the subdomains of the domain1 or domain1 itself.

Comment: Please put your folder structure.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand, what do you mean by folder structure

Comment: is this your own server, or from some hosting provider?

Comment: that is not a hosting provider but I am not administrating the server

Comment: @user2615859 What I meant was in the answer.

Comment: @user2615859: You can't use a URL as a directory.  (HTTP isn't a file system.)  If you're looking to list the contents of a folder, you need to provide it with the folder.  If this isn't working, then presumably `domain2.com` isn't the name of the folder relative to the code that's executing.

Comment: do you have access to domain2 codes? if yes then just do a local domain PHP glob or file reading mechanism to output it probably in JSON, kind of like an API. then domain1 does a cURL or file_get_contents to your JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that you have your folder structure in the server this way:

```
- www/
|- domain1.com/
|  |- hello.htm
|  |- image.png
|  |- photo.jpg
|  |- graph.svg
|  |- tasks.txt
|- domain2.com/
|  |- css/
|  |  |- style.css
|  |- js/
|  |  |- scripts.js
|  |- index.php
- cgi-bin
```

And if you would like to list out the contents of the `domain1.com` from `domain2.com`'s `index.php` file, you can access the folder structure using:

```
$directory = "../domain1.com";
$images = readdir(opendir($directory));
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
$count = 1;
echo "<table border=0 style='float:left;margin-left:115px;'>";
foreach ($images as $dispimage) {
  if (!in_array($dispimage, $ignore)){
    echo "<tr id='del_pl$count'><td>$count</td><td style='width:300px;'><a href='$directory/$dispimage' target='_blank'>../img/img_large/$dispimage</a></td><td><input type='button' style='padding:0;height:17px;' id='delete$count' value='Delete' onclick='deleteFile(\"$dispimage\",$count,\"$directory\",\"pl\");'></td></tr>";
    $count++;
  }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: i did read about it and tried but it is not working, I am not getting the files listed

Comment: @user2615859 perhaps there are some folder restrictions. like open_basedir etc.

Comment: i did try it this way too, but still no result

Comment: Grr... Can you update the question with the output of `phpinfo()` please?

Comment: which part of it do you need

Comment: Good question. But what's the error you are facing when you use `readdir()` or `scandir()` or `opendir()`?

Comment: this is what i am getting 

    Warning: scandir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/domain2.com/img/) is not within the allowed path(s)

Comment: @user2615859 Problem solved. This is because of your admin's restriction of one site cannot access another. You have to deal this with your admin and get the rights sorted ASAP.